# How to compare class annotated by @Entity field by field without degrading performance of storing object into db?

Tags: java, hibernate, equals

I have DB class that annotated with `@Entity` in `Java`.

I want to compare 2 instances of class that I want to compare field by filed but get error from `Hamcrest` that objects are not equal. It persists unless I auto-generate `equals` and `hashCode` in `Eclipse`.

The structure of the entity is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book extends BaseEntity {

  @NotNull
  @Column
  private String title;
}
```

and

```
@MappedSuperClass
class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

}
```

For simplicity purposes, I omitted all getters and setters.

Example code how I use entity above:

```
public void updateBookTitles(bookIds) {
  List<Book> books = bookRepository.findByBookIds(bookIds);

  books.forEach((book) -> {
    book.setTitle("Example: " + book.getTitle());
  });
  bookRepository.saveAll(books);
}
```

When testing this:

```
@Test
public void updateSingleBookTitle() {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setId(1L);
    book.setTitle("Stack Overflow manual");

    when(bookRepository.findByBookIds(Arrays.asList(1L))).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(book));

    updateBookTitles(Arrays.asList(1L));

    Book expectedBook = new Book();
    expectedBook.setId(1L);
    expectedBook.setTitle("Stack Overflow manual");

    verify(bookRepository, times(1)).saveAll(Arrays.asList(expectedBook))
}
```

Therefore, the question I have. Is there any way except auto-generation `equals` and `hashCode` in order objects to be equal during the testing and also, not to degrade performance when store into database. As far as, I understand at the moment objects are checked by `id` field not by all fields.

Comment: add some code example where create/compare that objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `samePropertyValuesAs` method:

```
Book book1 = new Book();
Book book2 = new Book();
assertThat(book1, samePropertyValuesAs(book2));
```

This will compare your objects field by field and perform assertions on equality of them to one another. If you need to ignore some fields - look at [Shazamcrest - Reusable Hamcrest matchers suitable for automated testing](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest#ignoring-fields).

---

**UPDATE 1**:

Try to use next code:

```
verify(bookRepository, times(1)).saveAll(argThat(new ArgumentMatcher<List<Book>>() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object argument) {
                List<Book> bookToCheck = (List<Book>) argument;
                assertThat(bookToCheck.get(0), sameAsBean(expectedBook));
                return true;
            }
        }));
```

More info : [ArgumentMatcher](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use something like Lombok https://projectlombok.org/ for data entities like this. Like equals, hashCode, getters and setters.